# Where to put shared controller code

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a shared controller function that I'd like to be reused across controllers:

```
  def render_unprocessable_entity(conn, changeset) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    |> render(ExampleApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
  end
```

Question: where can I put this? I've tried to put it into controllers/helpers/controller_helper.ex and it says: `undefined function put_status/2`. I can't just add `use ExampleApp.Web, :controller` in this helper because it will conflict with existing controller. I could use it as regular module and use alias, but that's more typing of `ControllerHelper` everywhere.

I could put it into web.ex maybe? But maybe I should not make that file too big?

What's the best way to DRY up the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.import/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2) to import all exported (public) functions from the desired module (from the helper in this particular case) without explicit namespacing:

**controller_helper.ex** (or any other module)

```
defmodule My.ControllerHelper do
  def put_status(param), do: IO.puts(param) # whatever
end
```

**my_controller.ex** (or any other module)

```
import My.ControllerHelper # ⇐ HERE !!!

defmodule My.Controller do
  use Waveia.Web, :controller

  def render_unprocessable_entity(conn, changeset) do
    conn
    |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity) # ⇐ HERE !!!
    |> render(...)
  end
  ...
end
```

---

Whether you want to have an access from the single module to all those *using* it, you might override [`__using__/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2) callback to import the module, that is calling `use Helper`.

The example of this would be:

```
defmodule ExampleApp.ControllerHelper do
  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      defp render_unprocessable_entity(conn, changeset) do
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(ExampleApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clarify enough. But I wanted to use that function in my controller, but put it in a separate module so it could be imported/used in other modules. I was looking for something like a ruby module within elixir, where the helper module can have access to all existing functions defined in whatever class included the module. For example, `has_many` or `attribute` methods could also be used in these modules.

Comment: If you want to have an access from the single module to all those using it, you might override [`__using__`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2) callback to import the module, that is calling `use Helper`.

Comment: Bingo! I think that's exactly what I needed. I ended up using ```defmodule ExampleApp.ControllerHelper do

  defmacro __using__(opts) do
    quote do
      defp render_unprocessable_entity(conn, changeset) do
        conn
        |> put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
        |> render(ExampleApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
      end
    end
  end
end
``` would you add this to your answer before I accept your answer?

Comment: @randomor appended to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

These functions ([put_status/2](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_status/2) and [render/3](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#render/3)) exist in other modules that are imported when you do `use Waveia.Web, :controller`

You can do:

```
def render_unprocessable_entity(conn, changeset) do
  conn
  |> Plug.Conn.put_status(:unprocessable_entity)
  |> Phoenix.Controller.render(ExampleApp.ChangesetView, "error.json", changeset: changeset)
end
```

You could define this in a module then `import` the module inside the `controller` function in `web.ex`, however it should be noted that any time you import functions in to a module, you hide where the module is defined. This means other people working on the code base may have to do some digging round the code to find where the function is defined. Instead, I'd recommend doing:

```
import MyModule, only: [render_unprocessable_entity: 2]
```

This way someone viewing the controller code can see exactly where the `render_unprocessable_entity/2` function comes from.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! It's just weird I have to explicitly specify the `put_status` module, which was a detail that's hidden in `use Phoenix.Controller`. Coming from ruby, I wonder if  there is a way to write the code as if the code could be copied into/or out from my controllers.